# Given $T(0)=0, T(n)=T(n-1)+n$ where $≥ 1$ use repeated substitution and prove formula valid.

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

$T(0)=0,  T(n)=T(n-1)+n$ where  $≥ 1$... 
Prove formula valid.

Deriving formula:

> k=1$$
> T(n-1)=T((n-1)-1)+n-1\\
> =T(n-2)+n-1
> $$
>   k=2$$
> T(n-2)=T((n-2)-1)+(n-1)-1\\
> =T(n-3)+n-2
> $$
>   k=3$$
> T(n-3)=T((n-3)-1)+(n-1)-2\\
> =T(n-4)+n-3$$
>   General formula: $ T(n-(k+1))+n-k$
>   $$n-(k+1)=0\\
> n-1=k\\
> T(n)=T(n-((k+1)+1) +n-(n-1)\\
> =T(n-(n-1+1)+n-n+1\\
> =T(0)+1\\
> =0+1=1
> $$

I am stuck at the above section when using the substitution method. Is there anything wrong with my working , I have checked it over many times.

Answer (score 1):

$T(n) = (T(n)-T(n-1))+...+(T(1)-T(0))+ T(0)= n + (n-1) +...+ 1= n(n+1)/2$

Comment: Please elaborate.